# Does uniform continuity of bounded continuous functions implies the same for all continuous functions on a uniform space?

Tags: general-topology

Recently I came to know about Atsuji space from [the paper](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v30/tp30120.pdf). A metric space $X$ is called an Atsuji space if every real-valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous. Strikingly I have found in the above paper that, **$X$ is an Atsuji space if and only if every bounded real-valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous.**

I would like to ask whether the same can be concluded for a uniform space.

**That is, can we conclude the following:**

> **For a uniform space $(X,\mathcal U),$ every real-valued continuous function (w.r.t. the topology induced by $\mathcal U$) on $X$ is uniformly continuous if and only if every bounded real-valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous.**

*Unfortunately I failed to construct a counterexample and consequently seeking some help.*

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose every bounded real-valued continuous function is uniformly continuous. It follows easily that every bounded complex-valued continuous function is uniformly continuous. Now suppose $f$ is a real-valued continuous function and let $g=e^{if}$. Then $g$ is uniformly continuous, and (this is the slightly tricky part that I leave to you) it follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

(Show first that if $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ then the definition of uniform continuity is satisfied, then show how the case $\epsilon>0$ follows...)